# C# .NET Core Configuration - alternative approaches?

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration, lazy-loading

I am looking for *simple approaches to the use of the Options pattern* for mixes of environment-agnostic, environment-specific and secret configuration in .NET Core. I have seen unnecessarily complex approaches to this, and developed one approach which feels much simpler than what I have seen, but still begs to be simplified further. I will provide that in the first answer to this question.

So, put as a clear question:
What is the simplest approach to Binding Options objects to Configuration sections in .NET Core that is a consistent approach across all types of .NET Core projects, e.g. Function apps, Worker services, ASP.NET Core, etc?

Bonus questions:
How can this approach be used without requiring the use of a Dependency Injection container?

- creating an instance of IConfiguration with a Dependency Injection container feels very messy to me in that IConfiguration then needs to be a parameter of every constructor within a chain of dependencies, *or it requires that* all class/interface implementations need to be registered within the DI container.

How can this approach be used *with* a Dependency Injection container?

- most people I've met *do use* DI containers (either Autofac or the .NET Core DI container) so it's definitely worth discussing how the approach might also be useful in a DI container scenario.

===========

It's worth noting that I completely adhere to the Dependency Inversion principle via Dependency Injection, but do so via chained constructors (typically two) and only minimally use DI containers in .NET Core - almost always for logging only. There are a number of reasons for this which are probably best stated by Ygor Bugayenko in Elegant Objects and not the topic of this post.

===========

One more thing:
I am *not going to* accept my own answer that I'm providing below. In fact, I'm not going to accept an answer for awhile so that there is plenty of time for alternate approaches to be provided in the answers.

Looking forward to your ideas! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

One approach to this is to create Options objects that lazy-initialize, and use an implementation of IConfiguration that has been stored in a singleton at startup that is available to the entire application in order to eliminate the need for DI container gymnastics. I believe that the following approach does not diverge from Microsoft's intent regarding the use of the Options pattern, but is a different and IMO simpler approach to doing so.

In this example implementation I'm going to use naive Singleton patterns for simplicity - if you're concerned at all with multiple threads creating multiple instances you might go with the use of the Lazy class or a traditional double-locking singleton pattern.

I'll use a RemoteCache configuration object as an example of an Options compliant model:

```
public class RemoteCache 
{
    private const string SectionName = "Redis";
    private static RemoteCache _instance;
    private static readonly Redis RedisConfig = new();

    public static RemoteCache Instance() 
    {
        if (_instance is not null) return _instance;

        _instance = new RemoteCache();
        return _instance;
    }

    private RemoteCache() { }

    public string CacheConnection => RedisConfigInstance.CacheConnection;
    public string CacheKey => RedisConfigInstance.CacheKey;

    private Redis RedisConfigInstance
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(RedisConfig.CacheConnection) is false) return RedisConfig;

            AppConfiguration.Instance.GetSection(SectionName).Bind(RedisConfig);
            return RedisConfig;
        }
    }

    private class Redis
    {
        public string CacheConnection { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string CacheKey { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Q. What is AppConfiguration and where does this get initialized?

A. A static class that gets initialized in your Startup class.

My Startup class for a function app typically looks like this. You might notice that I am using "appsettings.json" which is typically not done in function apps, but I wanted the environment-agnostic portion of my configuration to follow the same pattern used in non-function-apps, rather than shoving dang-near everything into Environment Variables which seems pretty typical of function apps and leads to a glut of environment variables being pushed in during the deployment process. I do use environment variables for secrets in non-local deployments, and use KeyVault references to acquire those secrets at runtime. When running locally, secrets are acquired using the UserSecrets.

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder) 
    {
        ExecutionContextOptions executionContextOptions = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IOptions<ExecutionContextOptions>>().Value;

        IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(executionContextOptions.AppDirectory)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false)
            .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", true)
            .AddUserSecrets(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), true);

        AppConfiguration.Instance = configurationBuilder.Build();

        builder.Services.AddLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.AddApplicationInsights(new ApplicationInsightsConfiguration().AppInsightsInstrumentationKey());
        }
    }
}
```

This is all the AppConfiguration class is:

```
public static class AppConfiguration
{
    public static IConfiguration Instance;
}
```

So, once you have your startup code and AppConfiguration class in place you can happily create Options model objects that map to your configuration sections to your heart's content. These models are implemented as singletons so you can then access them from whatever code needs configuration no matter how deeply nested in your application.

Usage example:

(I prefer accessing configuration models through an interface, which allows my code to be TDD with true unit tests that use fakes of config implementations [of course, use mocks if you prefer])

```
public interface IRemoteCacheConfiguration
{
    string CacheConnection();
    string RedisCacheKey();
}

public class RemoteCacheConfiguration : IRemoteCacheConfiguration
{
    public string CacheConnection() => RemoteCache.Instance().CacheConnection;
    public string RedisCacheKey() => RemoteCache.Instance().CacheKey;
}

public class MyThingThatAccessesTheCache
{
    private readonly IRemoteCacheConfiguration _remoteCacheConfiguration;

    public MyThingThatAccessesTheCache() : this(new RemoteCacheConfiguration()) { }

    public MyThingThatAccessesTheCache(IRemoteCacheConfiguration remoteCacheConfiguration) => _remoteCacheConfiguration = remoteCacheConfiguration;

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        string cacheConnection = _remoteCacheConfiguration.CacheConnection();
    }
}
```